# Regex IsMatch randomly failing to match pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have been struggling through an odd issue.  I have a set of regex patterns that I use to match and block hacking attempts against my website.

There is one particular pattern that is pretty common, however for some reason the pattern I have targeting it is not always matching the incoming url.

If I manually step through the code, or try and access the recorded URL myself, or use [REGEX STORM](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test the url, then my pattern always catches it.

Here is the regex pattern I have created.

```regex
(%20|\+)and(%20|\+)(%27|%22)\w(%27|%22)%3d(%27|%22)\w$
```

Here is a selection of the end of incoming URLs to my site, I have manually inserted the spaces so the portions that match the regex are all lined up.

```
SUCCEED (matched the regex)

=&txt_8=%22                    %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22y
xt_1117=&LookupKey=SBR_RAB%27  %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27y
xt_1117=&LookupKey=SBR_RAB%22  %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22y
SSBBRREF%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27y
SSBBRREF%22                    %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22y
e=SBRRAB%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27y
=&txt_8=%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27y
xt_1117=&LookupKey=SBR_RAB%27  %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27x
SSBBRREF%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27x
e=SBRRAB%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27x
=&txt_8=%27                    %20and%20%27x%27%3d%27x

FAILED (did not match the regex)

xt_1117=&LookupKey=SBR_RAB%22  %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22x
SSBBRREF%22                    %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22x
e=SBRRAB%22                    %20and%20%22x%22%3d%22x
```

Here is the code that runs it

```
var url = Request.RawUrl.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
    @"(%20|\+)and(%20|\+)(%27|%22)\w(%27|%22)%3d(%27|%22)\w$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
if (reg.IsMatch(url))
  BlockAttempt();
```

Considering that if I try and access the same url that was recorded in my logs and it correctly gets blocked by my regex when I do that, I do not understand why these URLs are occasionally slipping paste that particular portion of my security code.

So far my only theory is that somehow there is an invisible character at the end of the URL that does not make it into my log, and yet prevents the URL from matching a regex pattern ending in '$' from matching.

Does this theory even make sense, does anyone have any better ideas?  Is there possibly a bug in the IsMatch function?

Comment: In which locale are you working? string.ToLower behaves differently depending on the locale. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/32899/commits/a458fc05ff3bc9dedeb298314f41592aa4238994 where the Turkish I problem is checked. Consider adding RegexOptions.CultureInvariant.

Comment: You can try to call your web site with some chinese characters. It could be that your viewer shows characters for which your font has no glyph emtpy spaces or nothing. Try using a hex editor for the log file just to be sure.

Comment: These seem like some really good ideas. My database field is varchar rather than nvarchar, and I am working in en-US, but the calls (both success and failures) are coming in with a blank language string from a Netherlands IP.

Comment: I implemented the CultureInvariant suggestion (and updated the post to reflect it), but this is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [Regular Expression Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> By default, the comparison of an input string with any literal characters in a regular expression pattern is case sensitive [...]

The "D" in `3D` might be a problem. *(example string and pattern had different case in the original version of the post)*

Also, use verbatim strings (`@"..."`) to avoid C# treating the backslash as string escape character *(string was not verbatim in the original version of the post)*. Otherwise you would have to double the backslashes:

```
"(%20|\\+)and(%20|\\+)(%27|%22)\\w(%27|%22)%3d(%27|%22)\\w$"
```

With verbatim string and options

```
var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
    @"(%20|\+)and(%20|\+)(%27|%22)\w(%27|%22)%3d(%27|%22)\w$",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you are using this regex repeatedly, the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option speeds up your tests.

If you think that there might be a white space character at the end, use

```
(%20|\+)and(%20|\+)(%27|%22)\w(%27|%22)%3d(%27|%22)\w\s*$
```

See also: [Strings (C# Programming Guide) / Regular and Verbatim String Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals)

Comment: I perform a ToLower() on the URL before it is sent to the regex.  I updated the URL data in my post to reflect that fact. The regex is stored in the database, it is inserted in the post explicitly for clarity, so I don't think verbatim strings should be an issue.

Comment: Using the compiled feature, and caching up the regex would be a good idea for speed, but I do not see that being a cause in this particular problem.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: Using RegexOptions.Compiled and RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is  a bad idea because this combination is 50% slower than the interpreted one. I have fixed that for .NET Core here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/32899 Not sure if this made it into .NET 4.8 though.

Comment: @AloisKraus: This is quite an unexpected behavior. Good to know.

Comment: @JeremeGuenther: This is why you should post real code on SO.

Comment: Unfortunately that is no possible for many people due to both security reasons, and the complexity of production code.  I have attempted that in the past, and had to re-write the post because people got hung up on all the code they couldn't see rather than on the question itself.